# C# check if string exist, if exists show that string

Tags: c#, string, foreach

How can I get a single value from a loop that is matching my string.

I have a list of symbols that are sometimes contains more that 6 characters.

With current code I am getting last symbol from list.

So what I am trying to do is:

- search for specific symbol with more than 6 characters ex. EURUSD#1
- if it exists show only that EURUSD#1
- if it doesn't exist load EURUSD

Here is code and image bellow so you can see all list of symbols.

```
string defaultSymbol = "";
// get all symbols from market watch
foreach (string symbol in mt4.Symbols)
{
    Console.WriteLine(symbol);
    // if symbol length is greater that 6, there is a special symbol ex. EURUSD-X, EURUSD#, EURUSD-AX
    if (symbol.Length > 6)
    {
        // there is special symbol, ex. EURUSD#
        if (symbol.Contains("EURUSD"))
        {
            defaultSymbol = symbol.ToString(); // special symbol ex. EURUSD-X or EURUSD# or EURUSD-AX ...
        }
        else if (symbol.Contains("AUSCAD"))
        {
            // load another symbol ex. AUSCAD-X, AUSCAD#
            defaultSymbol = symbol.ToString(); // this need to load any other one that have more that 6 chars
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // thsere is no special symbol, load EURUSD by default
        // EURUSD exists
        if (symbol.Contains("EURUSD"))
        {
            defaultSymbol = "EURUSD";
        }
        else
        {
            // load another symbol ex. AUSCAD if EURUSD don't exists
            defaultSymbol = "AUSCAD";
        }
    }

}
Console.WriteLine("Symbol " + defaultSymbol);
```

Test strings:

```
AUDNZD#
AUDUSD#
CADJPY#
CHFJPY#
EURAUD#
EURCAD#
EURCHF#
EURGBP#
EURJPY#
EURNZD#
EURUSD#
GBPAUD#
GBPCAD#
GBPJPY#
GBPNZD#
GBPUSD#
NZDJPY#
NZDUSD#
USDCAD#
USDCHF#
USDCNH#
USDJPY#
USDSGD#
USDTHB#
XAGUSD#
XAUUSD#
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and copy/paste the strings as text, not images?

Comment: @RuiJarimba edited

Comment: @Sanja your code is exactly the same in the `if` and `else` conditions, is this intentional?

Comment: @RuiJarimba i updated code check it please

Comment: @RuiJarimba code is not intentional, its need to works like this, because if there is some lets say special symbol ( contains more than 6 chars ) i need to load that one, in other case if there is no special symbols i am using default that i defined manually. You can see in first statement `if (symbol.Length > 6)` i need EURUSDX is he don't exists i will load AUSCAD-X if it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not much clear. Based on what you have posted, You are currently receiving last value always and that is what not expected. If you are expecting only first match value from loop instead then you have to break loop once it found match using `break;` statement. So put 4 `break;` in your loop after below lines.

```
defaultSymbol = symbol.ToString(); break; //2places
defaultSymbol = "EURUSD"; break;
defaultSymbol = "AUSCAD"; break;
```

But in this case you will get only first match value and it depends on sequence inside your `m4.Symbols`

You code may have much more additional logic. If you can tell us what is type of m4.Symbols and post some example values inside m4.Symbols and tell us sample expected output then I can help you in more detail

Comment: m4.Symbols contains array of Symbol names, they can contain 6 characters ( that is normal ones ) and they can contain more that 6 characters ( that is symbols with suffixes ), like you can see on that list under my code. I need to loop through all to find just one that contains name that i am searching for in a string and use it outside of a loop. If it contains less that 6 characters then i am setting manually symbol that i want to use. I hope this is more clear.